# How to render multiple Base64 images in the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, base64, preact

I have to render base64 images for avatar due to privacy issues, all promises for thumbnails are being resolved correctly but base64 images don't render properly from the browser memory cache.

[image]

Strangely, it does show up all base64 after re-render (when I click the sort icon, it doesn't trigger re-fetch).

And one more item appears from the network tab. I don't have any idea why.

Could you help me to render all images in base64 format properly?

Here's code snippet.

```
uniqueReferrals.forEach(({ gpReferralUuid, state }, idx) => {
        if (gpReferralUuid && state !== "hqSent") {
          healthQuestionnaireReviewService
            .getPatientThumbanils(gpReferralUuid)
            .then((res) => {
              const { hasPhotos } = res;

              if (hasPhotos) {
                const frontThumbnail = res.photos.frontThumbnail;
                uData[idx].avatar = frontThumbnail;
                setReferralSummary(uData);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {});
        }
      });

<tr>
<td>
<Avatar
    className={classes.avatar}
    src={row.avatar}
    alt="Thumbnail"
/>
```

[image]